# id's and object names listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a listbox that i want to populate with contactpersoon objects that i created. 
The user completes a little form with a few textfields and when the user presses the ok button the contactpersoon object will be created.

The problem is now that i want to add the name property of the contactpersoon object to the listbox as an item. but when i want to delete it from the listbox i want to delete it by the id property of the object not the name property...

Can anyone help me with this. I tried using dictonaries but i didn't get them to work properly.

Can anyone please advise/help me with this?

Thank you very much..

BTW Iam sorry for my bad englisch :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the ToString method in the ContactPerson class.  For instance:

```
public class ContactPerson
{
    public string Name;
    public string Id;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Then, you can add the actual ContactPerson objects to your list box.  For instance:

```
listbox.Items.Add(contactPerson);
```

Then, when you delete, you can loop through each item in the list and read any of the properties of the ContactPerson object, such as:

```
foreach(object item in listbox.Items)
{
    if((ContactPerson)item.Id == ...)
    {
        // do work
    }
}
```

Comment: This was not exactly the way i wanted it but i modified it the right way for my code! this was a good eye opener thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

While Binding to ListBox, use this -

```
listbox.DisplayMember = "name";
listbox.ValueMember = "id";
```

You can store the ID as a hidden value like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the `ToString()` function of your ContactPerson class and add the whole object to the ListBox, not just the name.  The `ListBox.Items` is a collection of objects, not just strings.  The `ToString()` is used by the ListBox control to display the text value of the object.

Alternatively, you can create a `List<contactperson>` and use that as a DataSource, and just set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` fields of the ListBox.  `DisplayMember` would be the visible name, the `ValueMember` would be the ID field.